# Docs are broken : https://readthedocs.org/projects/radis/builds/19302835/

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, git, read-the-docs

First time using ReadTheDocs.org so I'm a little bit out of my depths here but I'm learning quickly I have gone through the code like a hundred times but I can't seem to find the error

The Documentation is broken and I can't seem to find out why
Apparently due to a missing test file : FileNotFoundError: Test file trimmed_1857_VoigtCO_Minesi.mat does not exist

```
Extension error:
Here is a summary of the problems encountered when running the examples

Unexpected failing examples:
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/radis/checkouts/develop/examples/plot_compare_CO_geisa_hitran.py failed leaving traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/radis/checkouts/develop/examples/plot_compare_CO_geisa_hitran.py", line 37, in <module>
    s_geisa = calc_spectrum(**conditions, databank="geisa", name="GEISA's CO")
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/radis/envs/develop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/radis/lbl/calc.py", line 534, in calc_spectrum
    generated_spectrum = _calc_spectrum_one_molecule(
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/radis/envs/develop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/radis/lbl/calc.py", line 800, in _calc_spectrum_one_molecule
    sf.fetch_databank(**conditions)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/radis/envs/develop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/radis/lbl/loader.py", line 1364, in fetch_databank
    df, local_paths = fetch_geisa(
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/radis/envs/develop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/radis/io/geisa.py", line 174, in fetch_geisa
    df = ldb.load(
TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'isotope'


/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/radis/checkouts/develop/examples/plot_newfitting_Tgas-molfrac.py failed leaving traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/radis/checkouts/develop/examples/plot_newfitting_Tgas-molfrac.py", line 35, in <module>
    data = scipy.io.loadmat(getTestFile(data_file), simplify_cells=True)["CO_resu_Voigt"]
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/radis/envs/develop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/radis/test/utils.py", line 77, in getTestFile
    raise FileNotFoundError(
FileNotFoundError: Test file `trimmed_1857_VoigtCO_Minesi.mat` does not exist. Choose one of: 
- hitran_CO_fragment.par
- geisa_CO2_fragment.par
- co2_cdsd_hamiltonian_fragment.levels
- CO_Tgas1500K_mole_fraction0.01.spec
- geisa_CO_fragment.par
- hitran_co2_626_bandhead_4165_4200nm.par
- hitran_co_3iso_2000_2300cm.h5
- cdsd_hitemp_09_fragment.txt
- geisa_O2_fragment.par
- calc_N2C_spectrum_Trot1200_Tvib3000_slit0.1.txt
- synth-NH3-1-500-2000cm-P10-mf0.01-p1.spec
- hitran_co2_626_bandhead_4165_4200nm.h5
- CO_Tgas1500K_mole_fraction0.5.spec
- Corentin_0_100cm_DownSampled_20cm_10pctCO2_1-wc-gw450-gr300-sl1500-acc5000-.spec
- hitran_2016_H2O_2iso_2000_2100cm.par
- hitran_co_3iso_2000_2300cm.par
- hitran_CO2_fragment.par
- geisa_H2O_fragment.par
- N2C_specair_380nm.spec
- CO2abscoeff_300K_4150_4400nm.txt
- slitfunction.txt
- cdsd_hitemp_09_fragment.h5
- CO2_measured_spectrum_4-5um.spec
- cdsd_hitemp_09_header.txt
- SpecDatabase_Test
- calc_N2C_spectrum_Trot1200_Tvib3000.txt or use force=True
```

above is the error statement for the website

[and this is the build link[1](https://readthedocs.org/projects/radis/builds/19302835/)

initially, I thought the error was coming from the hdf5.py file in the error message Isotopes seem to have been called but not referenced. but it turns out that it wasn't that.

An Idea I'm working with is that there should be a file added in the config or MANIFEST.in file.
[image: Manifest file picture]

The files are also hosted on github [docs](https://github.com/radis/radis/tree/develop/docs)

Comment: [You didn't include that test file.](https://github.com/radis/radis/blob/develop/MANIFEST.in)

Comment: You've got `include radis/test/files/*.txt`, `.spec`, `.par`, and `.levels`, but this one is `.mat`. (I also see a `.json` in that folder.)

Comment: are you saying that in the manifest file, I should add include radis/test/files/*.mat 

or edit the .mat file to be a .txt or .pre

Comment: @user2357112 I decide to add *.mat to the file